# Get caller information in RingCentral

Tags: events, ringcentral, caller-id

I would like to get caller name and other details for incoming call in 
RingCentral. Till now, I am able to get incoming call details using `DetailedTelephonyState` event but this does not provide the caller name it only gives the calling number.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't in the event at the moment. You can see the definition in the OpenAPI 2.0 spec here in the `ActiveCallInfo` definition which is included in the `DetailedExtensionPresenceWithSIPEvent` definitio. I've included the relevant excerpt below.

If you want this information in real-time, you may need to do a lookup via (a) user's RingCentral personal address book, (b) account's RingCentral company address book, (c) your CRM/helpdesk app, or (d) a third-party Caller-Id (CNAM) API.

To see if we can add this to the event as an enhancement, please contact me at my email address on my profile page.

- Ref: 
  https://github.com/grokify/go-ringcentral/blob/master/codegen/swagger_spec.yaml

`ActiveCallInfo` Definition

```
ActiveCallInfo:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    id:
      type: "string"
      description: "Internal identifier of a call"
    direction:
      type: "string"
      description: "Call direction"
      enum:
        - "Inbound"
        - "Outbound"
    from:
      type: "string"
      description: "Phone number or extension number of a caller"
    to:
      type: "string"
      description: "Phone number or extension number of a callee"
    telephonyStatus:
      type: "string"
      description: "Telephony call status"
      enum:
        - "NoCall"
        - "CallConnected"
        - "Ringing"
        - "OnHold"
        - "ParkedCall"
    sipData:
      $ref: "#/definitions/DetailedCallInfo"
    sessionId:
      type: "string"
      description: "Internal identifier of a call session"
    terminationType:
      type: "string"
      description: "Type of call termination. Supported for calls in 'NoCall' status. If the returned termination type is 'intermediate' it means the call is not actually ended, the connection is established on one of the devices"
      enum:
        - "final"
```